# Regex issue with currency class

Tags: c#, regex

Im using very good currency class in c#. Class working good, but when I need convert USD to IDR (Rupian Indonesian) I get this error

```
 "{lhs: \"1,0 U.S. dollar\",rhs: \"9 708,73786 Indonesian rupiahs\",error: \"\",icc: true}"
```

Issue is caused from space in 9 708,73786. I think that I need remove space. This is code about class:

```
   public static class CurrencyConverter
{
    public static string Convert(decimal amount, string from, string to)
    {
        WebClient web = new WebClient();

        string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={0}{1}=?{2}", amount, from.ToUpper(), to.ToUpper());

        string response = web.DownloadString(url);

        Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*(.|,)\\d*)");
        Match match = regex.Match(response);

        return System.Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value).ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Probarly I need modify regex, but I dont know what change:

```
new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*(.|,)\\d*)")
```

This is screenshot in visual studio 2010 (Windows Form)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend doing this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=rhs: \"")(\d[\s,]?)+");
Match match = regex.Match(response);
string value = Regex.Replace(match.ToString(), @"\s", "");
return System.Convert.ToDecimal(value).ToString();
```

Try it here: http://ideone.com/ySISDU

Comment: this row: Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=rhs: \")(\d[\s,]?)+"); show me error (seem syntax error)

Comment: Looks like it needed another `"`.  Could you try it now?

Answer (score 0):

Try and substitute globally:

```
`\s(?=[0-9])`
```

for the empty string, and only then process your input.

(note that `\d` in .NET languages match any Unicode digit, hence the use of `[0-9]` instead)